# MS Teams Share Dialog bug with Anchor link

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

I am opening share dialog with a link in msgText. It works fine when link is small but if link is long it doesn't show link at all.

For Example Long link they won't show only message and remove link.

https://teams.microsoft.com/share?msgText=Visit%20here%20for%20amazing%20google%20photos.%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fccw-720.wdf.sap.corp%2Fui%3Fsap-ui-version%3Ddevmsteams%23SalesOrder-manage%26%2F%3Fsap-iapp-state--history%3DTASCNVB8NKP5OAF3ZHAZEEBJ2WZ08RPD1P69AH5CT%26sap-iapp-state%3DAS481NYTPUN81SSS85M0XFQ6DLJ3HF9PPF00J0YL%22%3EClick%20here%3C%2Fa%3E

For small link it will work fine. Share dialog will show message and link both.

https://teams.microsoft.com/share?msgText=Visit%20here%20for%20amazing%20google%20photos.%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%22%3EClick%20here%3C%2Fa%3E

Is there any way to avoid this problem.

Also it makes link into small case which is problem when URL for some application is Case-Sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a general limitation to the length of the text message that you can use. (200 characters currently) Since your message is longer, it is truncated and then not displayed correctly.

Instead of specifying the link as part of the text message, you can specify it as a separate `href` parameter.

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/share?msgText=Your Text&href=someUrl
```

Pay attention that "Your Text" and "someUrl" must be url-encoded.

So this works for me:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/share?msgText=Visit%20For%20amazing%20Google%20photos&href=https%3A%2F%2Fccw-720.wdf.sap.corp%2Fui%3Fsap-ui-version%3Ddevmsteams%23SalesOrder-manage%26%2F%3Fsap-iapp-state--history%3DTASCNVB8NKP5OAF3ZHAZEEBJ2WZ08RPD1P69AH5CT%26sap-iapp-state%3DAS481NYTPUN81SSS85M0XFQ6DLJ3HF9PPF00J0YL
```

Comment: Thank you for reply I tried that as well but it didn't work. Is that worked for you after giving double quotes in URL in encoded format?

Comment: Updated links in the question

Comment: I am initially using that href approach only to supply link along with message text. But as link is long so looking for alternate approach by giving anchor link into msgText.

Comment: As i said the length of the message is limited. If you have a long link and want to include that in the message the only way I see for that is to use an url shortener like bit.ly

Comment: Hey @NineBerry do you know if there is a way for the text passed to the compose box through ```msgText``` to accept line breaks? Tried everything I know and can't seem to find a way. Is this a Micosoft imposed limitation?

Comment: @Verminous You can use `<br>`. Use url-encoding. For example: `https://teams.microsoft.com/share?msgText=Visit%20For%20amazing%3Cbr%3EGoogle%20photos`

Comment: Ah thank you! I seem now to came across another obstacle. 200 chars max... I am trying something like injecting the text into the compose box after load to go around this. Was trying localStorage but localStorage does not work across different domains (this is I am working on a Chrome extension) oh well I will need to think about this. Thank you :)

Comment: @Verminous Using Javascript, you can write apps that run inside Microsoft Teams itself. AFAIK the 200 character limit doesn't apply there when sharing content. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams-from-personal-app-or-tab

Comment: @Verminous Or you can use a webhook to send formatted messages to a certain MS Teams Channel https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook

Comment: @NineBerry thank you this is interesting. You think it is possible to use the webhook in a Chrome Extension? So I could send a message with no restrictions to users? I see that in this case it seems it sends to channels. I'm searching for a way to send to users.

Comment: @Verminous I'd propose you ask a new question. Someone else with more experience in that area might answer.